# Toggling ng-selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to toggle ng-selected options in Angular, but am running into some difficulty.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
<select ng-model="datacut.ages" multiple>
   <option value="" disabled="disabled">Please Select</option>
   <option value="0-15" ng-click="toggleSelect(datacut, '0-15')" ng-selected="datacut.ages.indexOf('0-15') !== -1">15 and Younger</option>
   <option value="16-19" ng-selected="datacut.ages.indexOf('16-19') !== -1">16 - 19</option>
   <option value="20-24" ng-selected="datacut.ages.indexOf('20-24') !== -1">20 - 24</option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.toggleSelect = function(dc, str){
    dc.ages.splice(dc.ages.indexOf(str), 1);
    //e.currentTarget.selected = !e.currentTarget.selected;
};
```

The problem is that when I click on an option gets selected on mousedown, and on release gets unselected.  The commented out code also does the same thing.

I feel like this should have a simple solution, but I can't really figure out an elegant solution.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: For clarification - I need to be able to have nothing selected, so clicking a single selected element needs to unselect it.  I also need to be able to select multiple options.

Comment: Why do you have the `toggleSelect`? That function removes your selection from the model i.e. the option will never get selected which is why it gets unselected. If you remove the `ng-click` and all the `ng-selected` it works fine

Comment: Yeah, I'll add an edit for clarification, but I want to be able to unselect things (so that nothing is selected)

Answer (score 1):

Your are using `ng-model` which does the magic for you. So `ng-click` and `ng-selected` is not necessary. See my working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4uft05ah/1/)

```
<select ng-model="datacut.ages" multiple>
  <option value="" disabled="disabled">Please Select</option>
  <option ng-value="'0-15'">15 and Younger</option>
  <option ng-value="'16-19'" >16 - 19</option>
  <option ng-value="'20-24'" >20 - 24</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can select AND unselect options?  So you can pick the '0-15' and then unselect it so that nothing is selected?  If so, there's something else wrong with my program

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to remove the selected age from the ages model. Then you need to use the ng-change directive. And remove the ng-click or ng-selected. But leave the ng-model to access the value on the method that remove the selected item.
See my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O4CmocfvgrPA5RzdImgN?p=preview)

```
 <select multiple name="ages" unseletable forbiden-opt="datacut.MIN_AGE" ng-model="datacut.chosenAge">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled">Please Select</option>

        <option ng-repeat="age in datacut.ages" value="{{age}}">
          {{age}}
        </option>
      </select>
```

**EDIT:** This should be made in a directive because you need to update the option html to unselect the option.

Comment: Yes that's is what `splice` do it deletes the item from array and i create the options of the combobox from the ages attribute of the controller

Comment: Okay.  I need to leave all the possibilities in the list.  I was splicing to try and remove them from the associated ng-model (which would remove them from being selected)

Comment: I am very confused. If you know that one option should not be selectable why no just disable it? Won't it be a better option?

Comment: All options are 'selectable' though.  I just want to be able to click a selected option and unselect it.  I can just use command click to do it unless I get a good solution.

Comment: @Dave M So I changed the implementation to a directive because the option with the 'bad' value has to be unselected manually.